# Put dynamic value inside a object value string

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and trying to get values from an array of objects.

```js
var jsonData = [{
    "role": "abc",
    "nextrole": "def",
    "goals": {
        "goal1": "goal 1",
        "goal2": "goal 2",
        "goal3": "goal `${a}`"
    }
  },
  {
    "role": "def",
    "nextrole": "ghi",
    "goals": {
        "goal1": "goal 4",
        "goal2": "goal 5",
        "goal3": "goal `${a}`"
    }
  },
  {
    "role": "ghi",
    "nextrole": "jkl",
    "goals": {
        "goal1": "goal 7",
        "goal2": "goal 8",
        "goal3": "goal `${a}`"
    }
 }];

var result2 = jsonData.find(obj => {
  return obj.role === "def"
});
var a = "any String";
Object.keys(result2.goals).forEach(function(key) {
  $('ul').append(`<li>${result2.goals[key]}</li>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2></h2>
<ul></ul>
```

As you can see in the example given I am able to get the object based on the role defined. but how to insert a dynamic value or any other variable value inside the goal 3, ${a};
if this is not the right way to do it, please suggest me a better way.
I am not able to find a way to do it. any help would be apricated.

Thanks

Comment: You can write `"goal " +a`, and define `a` before the array."

Comment: Thanks @JMP, it helped, but if I want to pass nextrole from the same object, then how to do it, like if my current role is abc, I.e first object, I need to pass its next role means def to this varible , is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the values as functions that can accept a param and return string:

```js
const jsonData = [
  {
    "role": "abc",
    "nextrole": "def",
    "goals": {
        "goal1": () =>  "goal 1",
        "goal2": () =>  "goal 2",
        "goal3": (a) => `goal ${a}`
    }
  },
  {
    "role": "def",
    "nextrole": "ghi",
    "goals": {
        "goal1": () =>  "goal 4",
        "goal2": () =>  "goal 5",
        "goal3": (a) => `goal ${a}`
    }
  },
  {
    "role": "ghi",
    "nextrole": "jkl",
    "goals": {
        "goal1": () =>  "goal 7",
        "goal2": () =>  "goal 8",
        "goal3": (a) => `goal ${a}`
    }
  }
];

const result2 = jsonData.find(({ role }) => role === "def");
const a = "any String";

Object.keys(result2.goals).forEach(key => {
  $('ul').append(`<li>${result2.goals[key](a)}</li>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2></h2>
<ul></ul>
```